# linear algebra, space vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulties in proving whether a particular E is space for example IR, so I would like if you could do this exercise.

Determine whether IR ^ 2, with the operations described, is a real vector space.

For any alpha (a) and IR belongs (x1, x2), (y1, y2) E IR^2 consider that:

(x1, x2) + (y1, y2) = (x1 + y1,0) and a(x1, x2) = (0, ax1).

Would like if you could prove the axiom of adding 2, and the following of multiplication:

.(u+v)+w=u+(v+w)

.a(u+v)=au+av [b(beta)] .(a+b)u=au+bu .(ab)u=a(bu)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer to mark the question answered. So, it seems the following.

The addition is clearly associative, but scalar multiplication is not, because 
$(\alpha\beta)(x_1,x_2)= (0,\alpha\beta x_1)\ne (0,0)=\alpha(0, \beta x_1) =\alpha(\beta(x_1,x_2))$
provided $\alpha\beta x_1\ne 0$.